# Проблема с import в python при написании unittest'ов

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Мне достался в "наследство" некоторый немалый по размерам проект.

Структура папок проекта примерно такая:

```
projectname
---somefolder1
---somefolder2
------somesubfolder
---------__init__.py
---------module1.py
---------module2.py
---tests
------testsomesubfolder1
---------__init__.py
---------recipy1.py
---project.py
```

Для разработки я использую PyCharm. Для запуска у меня создана конфигурация python в которой задано:

```
Script: D:\project\projectname\project.py
Working directory: D:\project\projectname
```

Я хочу покрыть часть проекта unit-test'ами.

Например, мне необходимо написать тест в `recipy1.py` для некоторого класса из `somefolder1/somesubfolder/module1.py`

Как мне правильно сделать `import` для `module1` в `recipy1`?

```
# recipy1.py
# как написать import для module1?
import unittest

class Test1(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_testtest(self):
        self.assertEquals(100,100)

    def test_fakeclass(self):
        obj = module1.SomeClass(10)
        self.assertEquals(10, obj.GetValue() )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Правильно ли я делаю, что пишу тесты в отдельной папке?

Имеет ли значение Working directory, указанная в конфигурации `python` для запуска проекта (запуска `project.py`). Какой Working directory мне необходимо указать для тестов?

Answer (score 4):

Для начала создай в папках somefolder1 и somefolder2 файл

```
__init__.py
```

Иначе ты ни когда не достучишься до своих модулей.
[docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages)  читаем внимательно;)

Comment: Только, как я вижу, в Somefolder1 ничего нет, так что создавать __init__.py надо в somfolder2 и test.